# How to setup ssl with cacert.org

Tags: ssl, https, ca

I have a free domain,say`example.ml`, and I hosted my files at byethost.com. I am trying to implement free ssl on my site. I have logged into cacert website. Added and verified my domain. And now I am stuck. I dont know how to set up an ssl certificate from this stage.

A step by step explanation will be quite a lot helpful.

Comment: Too vague and off topic. Try serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate a private key and save it in your file system safely.
2. Generate a CSR with it.

You can use openSSL for 1 and 2.
Refer : http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/generate-a-csr-with-openssl

3. Get the signed server certificate from cacert.org by copying the contents of your CSR to Server certificates -> New. Save it in your file system.
4. You need to point your Appserver/Webserver to the location where your private key and signed server certificate is stored. Read documentation.

If it is a Apache webserver you can refer: https://techstrum.wordpress.com/2014/11/25/how-to-enable-ssl-for-ohs-oracle-http-sever/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need the CSR (your public key with some information).

To generate it you have to use the tool that your server provide would be easier (such as Apache Tomcat :: using keytool, Linux :: using openssl)

Then, sending your CSR file to the certificate vendor to verify and insert Root certificate.

They will send you back certificate file.

So, you need to use this certificate file for import into your secret key which you get it from the key-pair generate process on the first step.

Finally, setup your key into your server and config some property in web server config file.

These are the concept, for the technical you need to know what platform you used and find the way to use their provided tool.