# Two-way (mutual) SSL with Glassfish3/4 or Tomcat 8 and self-signed certificates

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, x509certificate, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to implement two-way (mutual) SSL authentication, but I constantly get the following exception either on Glassfish3/4 and Tomcat 8 servers (the stacktrace is from Tomcat 8):

```
10-Feb-2016 17:13:41.579 SEVERE [http-nio2-18443-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun Error running socket processor
java.lang.RuntimeException: Field length overflow, the field length (7189180) should be less than 65536
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1373)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:807)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:775)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNio2Channel.java:394)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel.handshakeInternal(SecureNio2Channel.java:267)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel.handshake(SecureNio2Channel.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1064)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.run(Nio2Endpoint.java:1046)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint.processSocket0(Nio2Endpoint.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint.processSocket(Nio2Endpoint.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:83)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:76)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

With long searching, I only found [this link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267494?start=0&tstart=0) which shows the same problem but on JBoss. Is this really related to the size/number of entries in the key/truststore? I now have ~66.000 certificates stored, but as development goes on, we expect **way** more (like, hundreds of thousands).

With an almost empty keystore (only the server and one test client certificate in it), testing the SSL connection with `curl` is succesful...

**UPDATE**

Okay, I think I figured out that it does related to truststore. Here is the code snippet from `sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage.CertificateRequest`:

```
        // put certificate_authorities
        int len = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
            len += authorities[i].length();
        }

        output.putInt16(len);
```

The exception is fired in the `putInt()` method, so I assume I really have too much certificates stored. I'm generating self-signed certificates right now, so I have to have every generated certificate as a CA on the server to trust the clients, and this must be the problem. The question now is that is there a way to generate certificates from Java that are *not* self-signed (e.g. I could use glassfish's self-signed certificate as a CA - or can I)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly , you need to ideally use the certificate of your company or if you don't have one generate one for your domain for free using sites like http://www.cacert.org/                Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573576/how-to-setup-ssl-with-cacert-org/31399286#31399286

Comment: Yes, I think I need something like that; for now, I'll try to stick with Glassfish's auto-generated, self-signed cert. I'll set the issuer of the client certs to the Glassfish certificate, and sign the client certs with the Glassfish private key. It seemed to work locally, now I'm deploying it to live server to see if this works with the real clients as well!

Comment: [Origin-Bound Certificates: A Fresh Approach to Strong Client
Authentication for the Web](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity12/sec12-final162.pdf) and [The Token Binding Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tokbind-protocol).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I made it to work by creating certificates with issuer set to server's own certificate (in Glassfish, with alias `s1as` particularly) and signing it with the server's private key. Now I don't have to store anything on the server as it recognises clients because it knows their issuer as CA in its trustStore (essentially, itself).